# PHPMailer class with Gmail, sending two emails each time

Tags: c#, php, post, phpmailer

I have a console application that posts to a PHP page that (using Gmail and PHPMailer class) emails the user.

The problem is, the user always receives the email twice!

Here is my post from C# (I pass in uid for logging purposes.)

```
public static void PostUpdate(string uid)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/bin/server/check_table.php");
    request.Method = "POST";
    string postData = "check_table";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("[" + uid + "]- " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : HttpWebResponse( " + ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription + " )");
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the content for debugging
    // Console.WriteLine("[" + uid + "]- " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + responseFromServer);
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();

}
```

My PHP file consists of

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users as u JOIN value_store as v ON u.id = v.uid WHERE u.last_notification < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 5 MINUTE ) ";
$results = mysql_query($sql, $db_link);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $id = $row[0];
    $msg = "";
    if($row["inlet_moisture"] > $row["inlet_moisture_high_critical"]) {
        $msg = "Critical Inlet Moisture";
    } else if($row["inlet_moisture"] > $row["inlet_moisture_high_warning"]) {
        $msg = "Inlet Moisture Warning";
    }
    if($msg != "") {
        if($row["mobile_notification"] == 1) {
            if( sendMessage(($row["mobile_number"] . "@" . $row["mobile_carrier"]), $row["first_name"], $msg) ) {
                $res1 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_notification = NOW() WHERE id = $id",$db_link);
                echo "SMS Sent for [$id]";  
            }
        }
        if($row["email_notification"] == 1) {
            if( sendMessage($row["email"], $row["first_name"], $msg) ) {
                $res2 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_notification = NOW() WHERE id = $id",$db_link);
                echo "Email Sent for [$id]";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "Update For [$id] Complete!";
}
```

---

I have taken into consideration some debug options posted.

I have setup my console application to read the output from the WebRequest...
So I can see I am opening the posting the page, the POST is OK. I think there might be a closure issue because there are two rows in the database, and If I echo back the ID for each row I only get the last row (twice). I have tried updating my PHP while loop to output for which id(row) i'm using.

I still receive

```
Update For [2] Complete!
Update For [2] Complete!
```

instead of

```
Update For [1] Complete!
Update For [2] Complete!
```

See above for revisions.

Comment: You are calling sendMessage() twice. One for a real email address, and once for SMS. Don't know about your users, but my phone picks up on my work emails, as well as SMS, so I tend to get double notifications

Comment: yes, but this is a very different way of sending. To sms via email I email to [phoneNumber]@[mobilecarrier] and for email it is the users email address. I can verify that those calls are not ambiguous. One sends an email one sends a SMS. And if you are thinking i'm just nuts and seeing them as the same; One is SMS to my cell, the email is tied to a gmail account I read via Outlook.

Comment: Check the server's access log - is the php script being called twice? If so, then it's something with your c# code.

Comment: Now this is truly strange. Sat down at my desk this morning. unlocked my pc, ran the same code I had last night and it is only sending one message. All my debug code is returning expected results now as well. I would really like to know what the issue is and if it is going to come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code:

```
if($msg != "") {
    if($row["mobile_notification"] == 1) {
        // stuff
    }
    if($row["email_notification"] == 1) {
        // stuff
    }
```

Which is sending an email once if the mobile_notification is set to 1, and also sending an email if the email_notification is set to 1; this could be the cause. You may want to use

```
    else if($row["email_notification"] == 1) {
```

to only send the email if the mobile hasn't been sent.

Without knowing some more of the code or data, it's hard to say. Some things you can do to track it down further

Put an echo in the PHP sendMessage function:

```
function sendMessage($to, $toName, $body) {
    echo 'Sending mail...';
    // rest of the function here
}
```

and see if it's definitely firing that twice (it should be).

Now have a look to see what's coming back from the database each time

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    print_r($row);
    // script continues
}
```

It may be getting 2 rows back for each query, in which case you may look at your SQL query to see if that's correct.

Assuming it is, maybe the PHP file is being called twice, so put a debug in the C# file (I don't know C# so I'll leave the syntax to you)

```
public static void PostUpdate(string uid)
{
    // echo uid here
    // script continues
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/bin/server/check_table.php");
    request.Method = "POST";
```

By just printing some output, you can track where it's going wrong, and then look at why it's going wrong once you know that.

---

I've just seen that you're doing this...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
```

And then later on, in that loop, saying

```
 $results = mysql_query("UPDATE users...
```

And re-defining the result set you're already looping on. You can run a query without taking a return value;

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE users
```

or just give it a different name the second time

```
$results2 = mysql_query("UPDATE users...
```

And it'll probably work :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joe, The C# call is only being done once. I am already writing that out to the console. The php call to sendMessage is firing twice PER call. Please see my update for more information

Comment: As for the two if statements; I want the user to receive the notification both via email and SMS if they so choose. So that should be how that works.

Comment: Can you post your SQL? Getting the last row twice is probably why you're getting emailed twice, so anything you can tell us about your database tables will come in handy.

Comment: I have run the SQL statement in my PHPMyAdmin and It returns the expected row(s); Here it is `SELECT * FROM users as u JOIN value_store as v ON u.id = v.uid WHERE u.last_notification < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 24 MINUTE )`

Comment: See the bottom of my main post, it's much easier typing and being able to use newlines :P

Comment: The only thing funny I can think of is there are two fields with the same name in the result set. ID is contained in each table. I have determined that the first indexed ID is the one I want, so I grab it with row[0]/ Could this duplicate entry cause issues (especially when it's the primary index on each table)???

Comment: See my update to my original post. your fix did not solve the issue (although It was a good catch!)

Comment: Accessing row[0] shouldn't (tm) cause a problem. As a general rule, I prefer to name the fields I want, using ALIAS extensively, for example: ` SELECT u.uid AS user_id, u.name, v.something, v.else AS bar FROM users u INNER JOIN value_store v ON u.id = v.uid WHERE ...` - doing this, you won't get two copies of the ID, and it's a bit cleaner. Back to the drawing board for the issue :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3284/discussion-between-joe-and-rlemon)

Comment: @rlemon What turned out to be the issue in the end? :)

Comment: As mentioned above It just 'started working' (something we did had an effect, however due to caching? it was not apparent right away.) So no clue. But you were a great help with debugging.

Comment: Lol, the ones that fix themselves are the best, and the worst :P Glad it's sorted